# Why won't flash allow me to scroll down any further?

Tags: flash, debugging

I have a very long vertical line of small jpegs, but I can't get to the end of it to add more or take away some!

Any help?

Comment: This question is vague. Can you give a more detailed explanation as to the problem and provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the images using script rather than adding directly on stage, the stage has a limited area which it would appear you are outside